# showing jinternalframe before loading the data of the jtables on it

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I have a jinternalframe called screenRole, that frame contains some tables that load information from a database, it will take some time for the internalframe to be displayed because right after calling the setvisible method Im also calling loadtb (whhich connects to the databases and pulls the data)
What I need is to display the frame first and after that load the tables.
It currently displays the frame once it pulled the info from the DB's.

I tried many things to show the frame first (all those //comment lines in the code) to no avail.

Any other suggestion?

RoleEng screenRole;

```
        screenRole = new RoleEng();
        desktop.add(screenRole);
        screenRole.setVisible(true);
        //screenRole.show();
       // screenRole.setFocusable(true);
        //desktop.revalidate();
        //desktop.repaint();
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test");
        screenRole.loadtb(this.idf,rcode);**
        //screenRole. (this.idf,rcode);
```

Comment: The only thing that has worked so far is the showMessageDialog, but I dont want a MessageDialog to show before the internalframe but at least that made it appear before load the info from the DB

Comment: Don't add comments. Post all the relevant information in the question so it is found in a single place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `SwingWorker` to load the data in a separate `Thread`. Then when the data is loaded you can use the `done()` method of the `SwingWorker` to update the data in the table.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.